# Domain model for a notification system

Tags: asp.net, object-oriented-design, asp.net-mvc, domain-model

I'm trying to build a modular notification service in a ASP.NET MVC web application. The application generates notifications and the service is responsible for delivering the notifications to the right users. When creating a domain model for the notification service, inheritance naturally comes to mind.

[image: Notification domain model]

One of the requirements for the notification service is that users can be subscribed to particular notification types. For example, **User** can subscribe to receive **NewMessage** notifications but not **ProfileNotification** notifications.

How would one represent a relationship where a User has a Subscription to a notification type, but the notification type is represented through inheritance. Of course, this could be possible via reflection, but I was wondering if there was a domain model that came naturally from my requirements since I couldn't think of one.

[image: User has subscription]

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework Code First, but I think the question is general enough for any object oriented programming language.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it doesn't seem like you need to use inheritance at all - you can do this with a one-to-one and one-to-many relationship.

I would create three objects:

- NotificationTypes
- Notifications
- Users

Notifications would be each tagged to a NotificationType, and Users would be subscribed to multiple NotificationTypes.

Here's a visual model:

```
Notification Types:

type name
-----------------------
group
profile

Notifications:

message   | type
-----------------------
message 1 | group
message 2 | group
message 3 | profile
message 4 | profile

Users:

user name  | subscribed types
------------------------------
john smith | group
jane smith | profile
jack smith | profile,group
```

Comment: I don't quote follow this answer since the question is asking about domain models and you're providing database schema. As a database schema this isn't a very good one anyway. You can tell because of the comma in the subscribed types column.